# React app fetch works only sometimes on iPhone safari

Tags: node.js, reactjs, fetch

I have a confusing issue. I have a React/Redux front end that pulls data from TWO backends. One backend, I built myself with Node. The second backend is run by NASA.

QUESTION: The fetch call only works for the NASA API on iPhone safari. It does NOT work with my Node backend. It works fine on computers, just not my phone.

THINGS I HAVE ALREADY TRIED:

1. whatwg-fetch - this did nothing. It's still there, but it's not improving anything
2. REACT_APP_... - I made sure to name my API address with the prefix "REACT_APP.." to ensure create-react-app isn't preventing the data from coming through. It isn't doing anything helpful.

Here is a fetch call that works:

```
export const getNasaImage = () => dispatch => {
    return fetch('https://api.nasa.gov/planetary/apod?api_key=IBNbXHbyn8pC2k9EVxumOUauFaccdzinCD0WJcSA', 
    {
        method: 'GET'
    })
    .then(res => res.json())
    .then(imageData => {
        dispatch(setNasaImage(imageData))
    }); 
}
```

Here is a fetch call in the same file that does not work on iPhones:

```
export const getAllQuizes = () => dispatch => {
    dispatch(quizLoading(true)); 
    return fetch(`${REACT_APP_API_URL}/quiz/`, 
        {
            method: 'GET', 
        }
    )
    .then(res => res.json())
    .then(quizes => {
        dispatch(setAllQuizes(quizes.quizes))
        return dispatch(quizLoading(false));
    })
    .catch(err => {
        console.error(err); 
        dispatch(quizLoading(false));
        return Promise.reject();  
    }); 
};
```

Here is my config file, where the REACT_APP_API_URL comes from:

```
if (process.env.NODE_ENV === 'development'){
    module.exports = {
        REACT_APP_API_URL: 'http://localhost:8080'
    }  
} else {
    module.exports = {
        REACT_APP_API_URL: 'THEAPIADDRESS'
    }
}
```